# Литература по node.js

Tags: javascript, книги

Собираюсь изучать node.js, делая проект с использованием websocket. Подскажите, где лучше почитать про эти технологии и какие библиотеки надо использовать на сервере и клиенте (желательно jQuery)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Ильи Кантора есть бесплатный скринкаст по Node.js. Начни изучение с него.
http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast

Comment: кстати, скринкаст очень похож на содержимое той книги на которую я дал ссылку выше)

Comment: Скринкаст - великолепен, но только для того, кто уже крепко знаком с джаваскрипт.

Comment: Так если человек хочет изучить Node.js, то это уже по умолчанию надо хорошо знать яваскрипт

Comment: поскольку топикстартер в разрезе вопроса о серверной технологии (нода) вплетает вопрос о клиентской (джквери), - то складывается впечатление, что с джаваскриптом он недостаточно знаком.

Comment: спасибо, скринкаст хорошо помог

Answer (score 3):

Начните с основы - [Учебник Джаваскрипт](http://learn.javascript.ru/)
жквери - это всего лишь более удобная обертка над джаваскрипт.
нода - это не язык, это технология, в основе которой лежит джаваскрипт.
и еще - не в библиотеках счастье, а в понимании сути алгоритмического построения.

Answer (score 2):

В данный момент читаю эту книгу: [Node.js Разработка серверных веб-приложений на JavaScript](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7631421/) , для начала что бы разобраться в ноде и npm подойдет.
Почему сразу `jQuery`?
`jQuery` - это не панацея , и нужно понять нужна ли эта библиотека или ее аналог или фреймворк как `angularjs`, но в первую очередь нужно понимать как устроенна библиотека.

[Вот ссылка на бесплатный ресурс данной книги](https://scanlibs.com/node-js-razrabotka-servernyih-veb-prilozheniy-na-javascript/#download)